# Set and display Blazor view component from class property

Tags: c#, wpf, razor, blazor, dynamic-usercontrols

I am trying to render different pages based on a class property in blazor with only 1 tagg.

In WPF i was able to create multiple views and specify in the prop of an object which view to render with the UserControl class.

WPF Datacontext:

```
public UserControl DetailView { get; set; }
```

WPF parentView:

```
<UserControl Content="{Binding DetailView}"></UserControl>
```

This way i was able to dynamicly render diffrent pages based on the property.

I am trying to achieve the same thing in Blazor.
I don't want to use a bunch of If elses in my blazorView

Answer (score 1):

I think `DynamicComponent` is what you are looking for.

**Documentation:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0

**Example of using a `select` element to dynamically choose which component should be rendered:**

```
<select @bind="selectedComponentIndex">
    @for (var i = 0; i < componentTypes.Count; i++)
    {
        <option value="@i">@componentTypes[i].Name</option>
    }
</select>

<DynamicComponent Type="componentTypes[selectedComponentIndex]" />

@code {
    private int selectedComponentIndex = 0;

    private List<Type> componentTypes = new List<Type>
    {
        typeof(Component1),
        typeof(Component2),
        typeof(Component3),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **DynamicComponent** as [@Dimitris Maragkos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10839134/dimitris-maragkos) mentioned.

In my example the **views are razor components**.
Also PropertyViewModel is the parent of the BooleanViewModel, NumberViewModel and TextViewModel.

```
<div>
    @if(selectedType is not null)
    {
        <div>
            <DynamicComponent Type="@selectedType" />
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public PropertyViewModel PropertyViewModel { get; set; }

    private Type? selectedType;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (PropertyViewModel is BooleanViewModel)
        {
            selectedType = typeof(BooleanView);
        }

        if (PropertyViewModel is NumberViewModel)
        {
            selectedType = typeof(NumberView);
        }

        if (PropertyViewModel is TextViewModel)
        {
            selectedType = typeof(TextView);
        }
    }
}
```